# Ruby, Windows, spawn - How to rescue Resource temporarily unavailable EAGAIN?

Tags: ruby, windows, multithreading, powershell

I have to run external executables from my Ruby code on Windows, for that, i'm using the

```
    spawn
```

method.
Sometimes i have to run the same program very often, it executes itself very quickly then exits right away. It's not critical that i simply don't run the program for some seconds.

The problem is - sometimes i get this error :

`````
C:/Program Files/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open3.rb:193:in `spawn': 
Resource temporarily unavailable - identify (Errno::EAGAIN)````
`````

My attempts to safely rescue and/or prevent the main Ruby program from crashing failed with any method i tried, even with this example :

```
begin
  spawn( "#{cmd}" )
rescue Exception
  sleep 0.3
end
```

i couldn't get right results.

How to rescue this case OR How to correctly thread/fork and prevent the main program from crashing?
(if possible - without tweaking the kernel / other params to increase maximum processes?).

Answer (score 2):

I found out by carefully rereading the [Ruby Wiki](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/Process.html#method-c-spawn)

```
The parent process should use Process.wait to collect the termination
 status of its child or use Process.detach to register disinterest in their 
status; otherwise, the operating system may accumulate zombie processes.
```

I don't have this error anymore if i do :

```
pid = spawn( "#{cmd}" )
Process.detach pid
```